# MITM proxy - Get URL typed in browser

Tags: mitmproxy

I succesfully installed MITM proxy ( https://mitmproxy.org/ ) . What i want is to from all of that tracked stuff somehow extract only url typed in browser (something like browser history, just url typed in "url bar"). What criteria of packet filtering do i need to enter ?

Thanks

Comment: It tracks web traffic, not anything internal to the browser or OS.  The user might type bing.com but if you do that with F12 tools open you'll see a list of 200+ different requests including possibly some XHR requests to fetch suggestions for how to complete their typing.   Also, if they click on a link they will navigate to a new page without typing anything at all.  Both navigations (typing url, clicking link to url) will generate the same traffic

Comment: You may want to check `mitmdump` the UI-less version of mitmproxy. It usually prints all the URL on the console that are requested (of course not only the address bar entered URLs, but from every requested resource), therefore this would be closer to what you want.